# How do I pull the correct id in leaflet in js?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I managed to pass the id in the marker but in the click function it only gives me the last number of the id array, regardless of the marker selected.

I need each marker to have its own id and show me by clicking on it, not that everyone gets the last number of the array and is set on all.

```
        function mstMuc(){      
              bounds = [];
              bounds = L.latLngBounds();
              for (var i=0; i < dtMuc[0].length; i++){ //adicionando simucs no mapa
                url = L.icon({
                  iconUrl:icoMuc[dtMuc[3][i]],
                  iconSize: [20,20],
                  iconAnchor: [13,5],
                  popupAnchor: [13,5]
                });
              var latlng = [dtMuc[1][i],dtMuc[2][i]];
              var config = {draggable: false, url};
              var id[i] = dtMuc[0][i];
              marker = L.marker(latlng, config,id[i]).addTo(map).on('click',
                  function onClick (e){
                    alert(id[i]);
                  })
                arMuc[i] = marker;
                bounds.extend([dtMuc[1][i],dtMuc[2][i]]);
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
                getdate(2);
              };
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to:

```
 var config = {draggable: false, icon: url, id: id[i]}; //Icon "url" is in the config wrong. You have to add "icon: url"
 marker = L.marker(latlng, config).addTo(map).on('click',
    function(e){
      var id = e.options.id;
      alert(id);
})
```